# Workflow not deleting the current item in document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow2013

In my Document Library, I try to copy current item to another document library. After that I try to delete the my current item. Some time it is deleted, some time it isn't. I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow.

When I cancle Workflow, it is showing below message:

[image]

Below is my workflow code:
[image]

Comment: What are you updating in current item in the second action before deletion?

Comment: I am updating the one column value set Yes/ No Value. Thanks for reply Mohad Tahir. Issue is solve.

Answer (score 0):

I update my workflow with add one action after the copy document **"then pause for 1 min"** after this action current item is deleted successfully.